# Opening txt files with default windows text editor in golang

Tags: windows, go, cmd

I want to open txt files using default text editor application that set for, but I don't know where windows stores the application and file format associative. for example in Unix-like systems there is an enjoinment variable called $EDITOR that stores the path to default editor.

I did a lot of research but I couldn't find anything

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out how to open files with default apps in windows. All the things you need to do is opening file by its own. take a look at below example.

```
    exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "sample.txt")
```

Comment: You can also use `("explorer", "sample.txt")`.